# Reusable Form Component in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I use the form component to create a form and insert the data in a database with a JavaScript form processor.

I would like to create a reusable form with a fixed set of fields as a component that I can add to any page without filling the form dialog and without having to add the fields manually in each form component.

I can create an ftl with the required form fields but how can I store the data of the dialog in the component to avoid having to fill it everytime the form is inserted?

Comment: I cannot quite grasp the use case, though can't you use default values?

Comment: @Ducaz035 I would like to create a form that collects customer data for the site editors to add to any page. The way the form module currently works is you add the form component, fill in he dialog with the page to be displayed after success then add the required form fields. I would like to eliminate all these steps and just have a component that will create a form with preset fields and preset success page. I created a custom ftl and processor, it posts but and inserts in the database but it does not redirect to the success page and if there is an error it also does not show the error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to do this:

**a) Custom data handling through a model class**
You can create a custom component containing a form with your input elements. This will have nothing to do with the form module though. In order to process the data, the easiest way is to configure a [modelClass](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Templating/Rendering-content/Model.html) for your component an in it implement the ["executeEarly()" method](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Templating/Rendering-content.html#_early_execution_of_components) in the model class. In there, you can do whatever you need with the data transmitted by the form (You'll find the data in the MgnlContext).

**b) Auto-generate from sub-components**
If you prefer to use the form module for the data handling, you could create your custom form component which extends the regular form component and then [auto-creates the sub-components](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Templating/Template-definition/Area-definition/Component-autogeneration.html) (i.E. input element components) you need.